# Excel Function - SUMIF, Count by Background Color and Specific "Text"

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula, sumifs

I have an excel spreadsheet and I'm trying to Count & Sum based on "text" and "background color

```
F7 = "GED"
G7 = "GED"
H7 = "GED" & "Background Color is RED"
I7 = "GED" & "Background Color is RED"
J7 = "GED" & "Background Color is RED"
K7 = "GED"
L7 = "GED"
```

I want excel to look at the range F7:L7 and SUM all cells that have the text "GED" and background color is "RED"

I'm currently using this formula to count&sum :
=SUM(IF(F7:L7="GED",1,0))
and it will give me the total of cells with the text "GED" but I need to count the cells that have both conditions, "GED" and background color is "RED".

Comment: You can't use regular formulas for this. You can use a VBA user-defined function... though, is the background color applied manually, or is it from conditional formatting?

Comment: The colors are manually being added.

Comment: The colors are manually being added.